# Mocha testing Typescript source file: unable to import node modules

Tags: node.js, angularjs, typescript, npm, mocha.js

I have setup mocha to test typescript source files. I have successfully run a test on one file that only imported source files, but I'm seeing a failure running a test that imports a node module.

I am running this on the command line to run the tests:

```sh
mocha -r ts-node/register -r jsdom-global/register spec/**/**.spec.ts
```

In the test that is failing, the source file that it is testing has this import

```js
import * as angular from "angular";
```

And when the test is run, I see this error:

```sh
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bsacamano/testRepos/myApp/node_modules/angular/index.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bsacamano/testRepos/myApp/web/common/default/unsecured/shared-modules/services/flexlabel/flex.service.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/bsacamano/testRepos/myApp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1455:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/bsacamano/testRepos/myApp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1458:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bsacamano/testRepos/myApp/spec/shared-modules/services/flexlabel/flex.service.spec.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/bsacamano/testRepos/myApp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1455:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/bsacamano/testRepos/myApp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1458:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.exports.requireOrImport (/Users/bsacamano/testRepos/myApp/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:49:16)
    at async Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/Users/bsacamano/testRepos/myApp/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:91:20)
    at async singleRun (/Users/bsacamano/testRepos/myApp/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at async Object.exports.handler (/Users/bsacamano/testRepos/myApp/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:370:5)
```

I have a different test for a source file that has these imports

```js
import {IHttpService, IPromise, IRequestConfig} from 'angular';
```

and that test completes without error.

Also, the code works in production; I'm seeing that `angular` is defined and working.

Any ideas on what I can do to get the test to pass?

Update:

I think it has to do with the clown show that is bare imports. My web app is built with webpack, and webpack takes care of converting those imports when bundling.

Out of desperation, I tried building a bundle for my tests (which I really didn't want to do since I'm not distributing the file, but you know). I then ran mocha on the bundle, but I'm still getting the same error, `angular is not defined`, just with a different stack trace.

Update 2:
Even if I were to remove the "bare" import and replace with an import of the script relative to the file, it doesn't work. I don't get the ReferenceError, but the import just doesn't happen; if I `console.log(angular);` after importing it, I see that it is an empty object.

Comment: Try adding `import "angular";` to the top of your test file.

Comment: It didn't _fix_ it, but the error gave light to what the problem might be. It looks as though `angular` exists on the `window` object. Removing `import * as angular from "angular";` and replacing `angular` with `window.angular` resulted in a passing test.

Now, why the import works in prod but not tests is something I'll need to look into. Not sure if it is an acceptable workaround, but maybe it can be. We're in the midst of componentizing angularjs code ahead of converting to the latest angular, so it won't be around for long.

Comment: You need to provide a shim so that your module system can find it you don't want to rely on it as a global is that would lead to bad design. Something like _shim.js_: `import "angular"; module.exports = globalThis.angular;`. But the past is Shem. But you need to monkey with the path mappings in your loader to make it work correctly